# Regression/anova with imbalanced controls

Tags: regression, unbalanced-classes, contrasts

I am thinking of a regression setup where the dependent variable, Y,  is continuous and the predictor is a factor.  The data is an aggregation of multiple sources with similar and pooled controls but different treatments, so that the independent variable, X,  is a factor with C controls and then T_i levels of several different treatments, so that Sum_i(T_i) >> C, that is, there's much more treatment data than control data.  I would like to answer the question of whether there's any effect across any of the experiments due to treatment, and in principle it should be answered by a simple regression of the form Y~as.factor(X), but what gives me pause is that dummy contrasts (which is seemingly what I'd like to test -everything against controls) are overloaded.  Should I consider an alternative contrast design?  I can't think of a one which would have the meaning that I want.  Or maybe the fact taht there are fewer controls is taken care of in computing degrees of freedom?